# What is the name of following formula?

Tags: geometry

What is the name of following formula?
$$
S=\sqrt[]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)}
$$
where
$$
a+b+c+d=2p
$$
$S$ is the surface of a quadrangle.

$a, b, c, d$ are lengths of sides of a quadrangle that can be inscribed into a circle.

Comment: @Sawarnik In Italy I've *always* used $p$ for semi-perimeter and $s$ for surface.

Comment: @Bakuriu But everywhere I have seen uses $s$ as the semi-perimeter! Do you remember Heron s formula with $p$ as the semiperimeter?

Comment: @Sawarnik Absolutely yes. Proof: wikipedia page on [Heron's formula](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_di_Erone).

Comment: @Bakuriu That is really odd! But most of the world uses $s$, I think. English Wikipedia can be a proof for that. Oh, I see he is from Poland, and the Polish Wiki does use $p$!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brahmagupta's formula. You can do a google search. Or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) is the wikipedia link.

Comment: Hmm...nice answer badge :)

Comment: @Sawarnik yep :)

Comment: Interestingly I didn't know the name of this formula 10 mins before answering. The credit is due to *another* question. I get a silver badge and 115 rep for free. :D

Comment: I know..the pentagon question after mine, isn't it? It was a nice Q, its inspired me to read stuff about Robbins pentagon and so...but how come a 1 line answer get 10 upvotes, I am jealous of you..btw, reputation is a useless thing.

Comment: @Sawarnik yep. The one after yours. It was weird though, two different people asking about pentagons in such a short while. Since when are cyclic pentagons the new trend?

Comment: @Sawarnik I have no idea. Maybe because it was quick, and to the point? :D The Q&A system is weird. :p The other day I guy asking how to subtract got 7 upvotes.

Comment: btw since we were talking about reputation, yeah its useless after around ~300(you need enough rep to be able to downvote, survive downvotes, and survive the rep of cost of downvoting). *But* if you go to the users page and sort by rep gained in the last week, I am at [position 11](http://i.imgur.com/fMcwxUM.png) as of now. :D

Comment: Will you come to chat, we can chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13523/the-root-of-math ?